# Capturing multiple instances of the same group in java regex

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I'm trying to extract parameter names from a string of pascal code using regex, This is the most complex of what I'm trying to work with. Note there will never be white space and parentheses will always be present.

```
(rate:real;interest,principal:real)
```

I've currently got the re as follows:

```
[(](?:([\w]*)(?:[:][\w])?[;|,]?)*[)]
```

I was hoping that I could access each of the capture group as the re passes over the parameter but apparently I cannot. For the example above the values I need would be "rate", "interest" and "principal".

Is there a solution for this? My own efforts led me [to here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html#reset_groups) where they mention using

> "matcher() with while… find()".

I don't completely understand regular expressions and would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `positive lookbehind` for this as

```
((?<=[\(,;])[A-Za-z_]\w*)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(
  (?<=   #Positive look behind
    [\(,;] #Finds all position that have bracket, comma and semicolon
  )   
  [A-Za-z_]\w* #After finding the positions, match all the allowed characters in variable name following that position
)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cX3yB8/2)**

```
String line = "(rate:real;interest,principal:real)";
String pattern = "((?<=[\\(,;])[A-Za-z_]\\w*)";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/5vn13A)**

Comment: Thank you! this is exacly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it with a relatively simple regex:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String simple = "(rate:real;interest,principal:real)";
        String regex = "(\\w+:|\\w+,)";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(simple);

        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group().substring(0, m.group().length() - 1));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid I don't know pascal, but it seems that the names you are after either end with a colon or comma. The regex looks for those strings and then removes the last character (either a colon or comma).

The output I got from a test run was:

```
rate
interest
principal
```